# How can I make a button that that triggers a script?

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to create a button that you can click to start a script. I want to have the button be able to be clicked more than once to do the script multiple times, and make the button have a price that takes from my "clicks" variable.

```
 <div class="game-object">
<script type="text/javascript">
   var clicks = 0;

document.getElementById("push").addEventListener("click", updateClickCount);

function updateClickCount() {
var el = document.getElementById("clickCount");
el.innerHTML = clicks;
el.style.color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
el.style.fontSize = '70px';
}

</script>

<script>
var clicks = 0;
 window.setInterval(
 function () {
     clicks = clicks + 1;
     document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

 }, 1000);
</script>

<button type="button" onClick="clicks++;updateClickCount();" id="push"     style="width:400px;height:60px;"><font size="5" face="verdana" color="white">Click me for Cola!</font></button>
<div id="clickCount"></div>
```

I do not know where in the code to put the button.

Seb

Comment: you want the script to be called after 1 second?

Comment: I would like the script to be called right away.

Comment: Either bind the handler with `addEventListener` or with the `onclick` attribute, but not both. When you use `addEventListener`, you need to run that code after the DOM is loaded, so you should put the script after the HTML.

Comment: @SebastienBolh so whats the `setInterval` part?

Comment: I just started coding, and I thought it was the way to add to the variable every second.

Comment: So you want a counter that keeps counting and adding to a number while a key is pressed and just when you release the mouse button the counting should be stopped?

Comment: Close, I want to have the button to just be pressed once, and the +1 clicks per second starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="push" style="width:400px;height:60px;">
    <font size="5" face="verdana" color="white">Click me for Cola!</font>
</button>
<div id="clickCount"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;

    var h = null;
    $("#push").click( function(){
        var el = document.getElementById("clickCount");
        el.innerHTML = clicks;
        el.style.color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        el.style.fontSize = '70px';
        if(!h){
            h = window.setInterval(function () {
                clicks = clicks + 1;
                document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML = clicks;
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Did you try running your snippet? It gets an error.

Comment: I like that it constantly updates, but I would like to have a button to start the +1 clicks per second, not just have it automatically there.

Comment: @ Sebastien Bolh  Have to try current demo